# az cli logging into wrong account

Tags: windows, azure, azure-cli

I have az cli version 2.44.1 installed. When I perform `az login` from the command, I get prompted to login on the browser. I then proceed to use my account `x@abc.com`. Once the login on the browser is successful, my command prompt shows a message saying "No subscriptions found for `y@abc.com`". For some reason, azure cli is picking up a different account (the account I'm logged on the PC as) instead of the account I'm selecting in the browser.

I have deleted the contents of `.azure` folder and redone the steps (hoping to flush the stored credentials) but the result seems to be the same; despite of me selecting `x@abc.com` on the logon window, I see that `y@abc.com` is selected by the azure CLI.

One workaround I have is: I can run the cmd.exe as a different user `x@abc.com` and then run `az login` from there. This way seems to pick the right account. But I'd like to see if there's a way to fix it some other way because I'd like to use az cli alongside terraform in my VSCode bash. I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

*I got the same error when I tried it previously in my environment, and I found the issue.*

[image]

*Reason:*

"***No subscriptions found***" ***indicates that the account has gone through authentication and does not have access to the subscriptions***.

Go to `Azure -> All Services > Subscriptions` or search for subscription in the search panel, then visit Access control (IAM) and assign the **"contributor"** role as shown:

***Path:***

[image]

*Script:*

```bash
az account set --subscription <subscription> //not manadatory
az login --service-principal --username <APPID> --password <clientsecret> --tenant <>tenantID
```

***Logged in successfully:***

[image]

***Parallelly,***

*Upgrade CLI once by giving:*

```bash
az upgrade
```

*to check your "CLI is upto date".*

[image]

*Execute the command below to check the cli login details for future use.*

```bash
az login --debug
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the issue is related to the credentials stored on your Windows machine. One solution could be to clear the Azure Active Directory (AAD) token cache by running the following command in the command prompt:

```bash
az account clear
```

This command will clear the AAD token cache, which will force the CLI to prompt you to login again and select the correct account.

Another solution would be to check the environment variables on your machine to ensure that the correct tenant and subscription are being used. You can check the tenant and subscription by running the following commands:

```bash
az account show
az account list
```

If the wrong tenant or subscription is being used, you can set the correct one by running the following commands:

```bash
az account set --subscription="SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
az account set --tenant="TENANT_ID"
```

You can also check and manage the stored credentials in the Credential Manager on your Windows machine.

It is also possible that there is a problem with the installed version of Azure CLI, you could try to update or reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks for this Luiz. Unfortunately the `az account clear` didn't work. The deletion of .azure folder would have had the same effect. As for the second part, the subscription and tenant are on a lower level. Since the account itself is wrong, I don't think the subscription and tentant selection would matter. Credential manager was a good point but I don't see my AAD details stored there :|